# How to parse JSON in Postman Test Script

Tags: json, postman

I am running a chain of collections from 1 API call to another. I want to pull the response body from API call 1 to API call 2 so that it can post the data to my application.

I have created the environment variables and in the tests tab I have created a script to set the variables but when I run the script I get a response of the below:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

My test script is:

```
bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

value = bodyData.[1]country

console.log(value)
```

The response body looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Country": "United Kingdom",
    }
]
```

I know the issue is [] and needs to have a string before it but the API is not defined with a string and I cant just use the below as it's then undefined:

```
bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

value = bodyData.country

console.log(value)
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting multiple variables in Postman JSON test scrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540416/setting-multiple-variables-in-postman-json-test-scrip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the reference slightly wrong I think.

This should do it:

```
let bodyData = pm.response.json()

let country = bodyData[0].Country

console.log(country)
```

To then set the variable you would need to use:

```
pm.environment.set("country", country)
```

Comment: how can i set multiple variables in the above i.e
let bodyData = pm.response.json()

let country = bodyData[0].Country
let postcode= bodyData[0].postcode

console.log(country,postcode)

pm.environment.set("country","postcode", country, postcode)

Comment: You would need to do that individually and set each as it's own variable. There are ways to get all that data into a single object and save it as a variable, then grab the data you need in future requests. If you raise another question with more of the details I can help you with that.

Comment: Hi Danny, posted under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540416/setting-multiple-variables-in-postman-json-test-scrip