# setting multiple variables in Postman JSON test scrip

Tags: json, postman

i have the below

```
let bodyData = pm.response.json()

let country = bodyData[0].Country

console.log(country)

pm.environment.set("country", country)
```

but i want to set multiple variables. I have around 8 different variables in my environment and i tried the below but it doesnt work

```
let bodyData = pm.response.json()

let country = bodyData[0].Country
let postcode = bodyData[0].Postcode

console.log(country,postcode)

pm.environment.set("country","postcode", country, postcode)
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479494/postman-can-i-save-json-objects-to-environment-variable-so-as-to-chain-it-for-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create separate `.set()` statements to capture and reuse the different variables in other requests.

```
pm.environment.set("country", country)
pm.environment.set("postcode", postcode)
```

Comment: for a sendRequest format, this worked for me (finally):

```function (err, res) {
        let response = res.json();
        pm.environment.set("country", response.country);
        pm.environment.set("postcode",response.postcode);
    });```

(sorry for the ugly format. I can't figure this out yet for comments)